# Instalacion phalcon phalcon ERROR: Please run composer install

Tags: php, windows10, phalcon

Estoy realizando la instalacion phalcon en win10 y al finalizar la instalacion y validar en cmd phalcon me arroja phalcon ERROR: Please run composer install,

Agrego fotos de toda la configuracion q tengo hasta el momento(ya carge devtools de phancon y hasta ahi todo correcto pero al validar la instalacino en cmd salta el error(ultima imagen.) )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de tener instalado composer si ya lo tienes instalado ve a la ruta de tu proyecto y abre la terminal ahí y ejecuta el comando:

```sh
composer install
```

Este comando te instalará todas las dependencias(librerías) necesarias para trabajar con *phalcom*.

Si necesitas instalar `composer` te dejo el link [aquí](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Si lo que necesitas ver es si `phalcon` esta instalado debes ver tus configuraciones con `phpinfo()`, te dejo un enlace donde se explica el proceso: [comprobar si phalcon esta instalado](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/phalcon/phalcon_environmental_setup.htm)

Puedes ver más detalles del phpinfo [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Según tus capturas ya tienes instalado phalcon en tu entorno de PHP correctamente, pero lo que te falta para tener accesible el comando phalcon en tu cmd, ese ya es otro proceso para el que debes hacer lo siguiente:

- Instalar phalcon-devtools y agregarlo al PATH tal y como te lo indica el enlace oficial: [click aquí](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/es-es/devtools-installation)
- Cuando agregues la variable al Path cierra el cmd y vuelve lo a abrir para que actualice la variable PATH de nuevo.
- Otro enlace más para que hagas doble verificación [click aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/phalcon/phalcon_environmental_setup.htm)

En la captura que agregas debes modificar la siguiente parte:

```sh
php %PTOOLSPATH%\phalcon.php %*
```

Te falta falta la `\` y deja el espacio despues de `.php`

Espero esto te ayude y oriente un poco más sobre el punto en el que estas teniendo problemas, saludos.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, si ya tengo instalado COMPOSER pero aun no quiero crear un proyecto solo queria validar si phalcon esta bien instalado y ver la version instalado sin embargo al colocar phalcon me sale ese error, segun me comentas tengo q crear un proyecto para q phalcon funcione, perdon mi ignorancia pero estoy empezando con esto, igual probare lo q me dices y te comento gracias.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, debes apoyarte del `phpinfo()` asegurate de tener habilitado phalcon desde tu `php.ini` ahí te deje 2 enlaces.

Comment: Allexiussw  acabo de actualizar la pregunta anadi todas las configuraciones q hice ya las habia hecho tal y como me indica tus enlaces aun asi no se cual es el error del por que phalcon no levanta, agregue fotos de mi configuracion a ver si me ayudas  saber q puede ser, gracias.

Comment: @PedroLuisSilvaRojas en las extensiones no es necesario que dejes el `.dll`, tambien recuerda reiniciar apache tras cualquier cambio que realices.

Comment: @JosueArriola en mi caso si es necesario xq de lo contrario no lo reconoce y me arroja error de que no encuentra las dlls, pero gracias por el comentario aun asi sigo con el error. Por el reinicio tambien lo hice  hasta reinicie equipo pero nada sigue el error de phalcon.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, veo que estas teniendo problemas con phalcon-devtools y agregar el ejecutable al PATH.. Me dejas el update de como te va.

Comment: @allexiusw gracias por el apoyo pero los pasos del enlace que mencionas si los habia realizado actualice la pregunta con la ultima imagen donde esta la configuracion del devtools si lo registre tambien en el path con la direccion y tambien reinicie todo pero aun asi el error persiste.solo  con la unica diferencia q si yo pongo en la ultima linea solo phalcon xq si pongo phalcon.php me arroja un error (C:\Users\plsil>phalcon
Could not open input file: C:\xampp\phalcon-devtools-master\phalcon.php) pero si lo coloca solo PHALCON si lo reconoce asi como esta en la imagen. igual me error composer

Comment: Verifica esta linea `php %PTOOLSPATH%\phalcon.php %*` te falta la \ y deja el espacio despues de `.php`.

Comment: @allexiusw tambien coloque de esa forma y no corre si coloco asi como me indicas %\phalcon.php % me arroja el siguiente error (C:\Users\plsil>phalcon Could not open input file: C:\xampp\phalcon-devtools-master\phalcon.php) por eso es que coloco solo %\phalcon %

Comment: @allexiusw acabo de actualizar la ultima imagen para q veas q me sale en cada caso segun como me lo planteaste, como puedes ver en ambas hay errores diferentes pero aun con el error.

Comment: Alguien pudo arreglar este error:
ERROR: Please run composer install